# They's were bought from restaurant near mummy's company

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I bought noodles from the Chinese restaurant.

The restaurant is near my wife's company.

My son wanted to eat noodles this morning and asked where the noddles bought from.

> "The noodles were bought from a Chinese restaurant where near mummy's
>   company."
>
> "They's were bought from restaurant near mummy's company"

Between noun and noun, is "where" neccessarily to add in?

Comment: Not ***They's***, but ***They*** - _**They** were bought from a restaurant near mummy's company._

Comment: Also, don't forget that *restaurant* is a countable noun, and therefore always has to have a determiner, like **the** restaurant near mummy's company, or **a** restaurant near mummy's company.

Comment: Rather than just ask, it would be better if you tell us why you wanted to insert "where" into your example.

Comment: You could use "The noodles were bought from a Chinese restaurant. Where? Near mummy's company." as a dialog. But not in one sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be "where near" but "near where mummy works" or "near where mummy's company is located" or "near mummy's company".

**where** heads a clause that requires subject and verb.

> The guide took them where the fish were plentiful.
>
> I left the car where mummy works.
>
> The restaurant is near where mummy's company is (located).

The restaurant is near {a place}.

The restaurant is near {mummy's office}.

The restaurant is near {where mummy works}.

There are times when it may appear as though the *where*-clause lacks subject and verb, but these  cases can be understood as a form of ellipsis:

> The guide told them that bow-fishing was possible, but only *where permissible*.

There, it is as though the words [it is] have been dropped: "where *it is* permissible".

"where permissible" is actually a clause with an implied subject and verb.